# String parsing in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, expression

I have string column `email_id`; the data will look like this:

```
email_id 
"1"
"6"
"3 4"
"8"
"0 3"
"0 5 7"
```

I want to get list of ids as integer. If I have two numbers in my string,  I want the last one. My result should look like;

```
SELECT some_function (email_id ) FROM table
1
6
4
8
3
7
```

Is it possible to do this in SQL Server?

Comment: You haven't explained why "3 4" is parsed as 4 and "0 3" as 3. Are these space-delimited lists where you always take the last integer? If so, CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING can help you. If not, you need to explain your logic.

Comment: I just re-read it, the OP does say "the last one"

Comment: If i have two numbers in my string, I want the last one.

Comment: Will it ALWAYS be either one or two numbers?

Comment: @Dems it can be more than 2. have updated my question now to make it clear.

Comment: This is not the correct way to represent a one to many relationship. You should have a separate table with one row for each `entityId, emailId`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
  CAST(RIGHT(email_id, LEN(email_id) - CHARINDEX(' ', email_id)) AS INT)
FROM
  yourTable
```

IF and ONLY IF, all your values can reliably be cast to an INT, and there is only ever one space at most.

**EDIT** To deal with a list of `n` values

This isn't pretty, but it avoid recurrsion and/or loops.  If someone gives an answer without REVERSE() test to see if it's faster than this or not.

```
SELECT
  CAST(
    REVERSE(
      LEFT(
        REVERSE(email_id),
        CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(email_id) + ' ') - 1
      )
    )
    AS INT
  )
FROM
  yourTable
```

Comment: This is working if i have only two values. Anyway it was helpful, Now I'mtrying to edit your SQL to make it work for more than two numbers...thx

Comment: @Ba1a - Updated using REVERSE() and LEFT() to take the last item, regardless of how many items there are.

Comment: select CAST(REVERSE (LEFT ( REVERSE ('3 4 15'), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE ('3 4 15')))) AS INT)

This itself working fine...I didn't understand why did you add space in the reversed email-id.

Comment: The `+ ' '` is needed for when there is no space in the string (You'll get `CAST('' AS INT)` otherwise).  And the `- 1` is there for 'purity sake' to avoid having a space in the string being CAST to an INT.

Comment: Ok. I was handling single number by CASE statement like ; 

SELECT CASE WHEN LEN('3 4 15')> 1 THEN CAST(REVERSE (LEFT ( REVERSE ('3 4 15'), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE ('3 4 15')))) AS INT) ELSE CAST('3 4 15' AS INT) END

Comment: @Ba1a - That won't work for '13'.  If you use case, use `CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(email_id)) > 0` [Remembering that SQL Server can recycle this result later in the function, so it's better than using `CHARINDEX(' ', email_id)`]

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT CAST(replace(your_column ,' ','') as int)  FROM table
```

Comment: select CAST('3 4' AS INT)  -- This row will fail ..I need to get 4 as value for this row

Comment: @Dezigo - And for the records that have multiple IDs separated by a space?

Comment: This will fail on values like "3 4"

Comment: u need to add replace function

Comment: Dems - oh. OK. I have missed it.(